# Как получить значение атрибута js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, атрибуты

Пытаюсь подключить ползунок. Значение, которое нужно получить находится в атрибуте `aria-valuetext`.
Я его уже писал (в js) и `aria-ValueText`, `aria-valueText` - но ничего не происходит.

HTML

```
<div class="testt" data-handle="0" tabindex="5" role="slider" aria-orientation="horizontal" aria-valuemin="0.0" aria-valuemax="100.0" aria-valuenow="25.0" aria-valuetext="4000" style="z-index: 4;"></div>
  <button type="submit" id="super">Отправить</button>
  <div id="resval"></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
function btnfunc() {
  var price = document.getElementsByClassName('testt')[0]["aria-valuetext"];
  document.getElementById('resval').innerHTML = price;
}
document.getElementById("super").onclick = btnfunc;
```

---

И еще вопрос, если я хочу получить значение не по нажатию на кнопку, а по `onclick`, будет ли рабочим добавление атрибута через js?

```
$(".testt").attr('onclick', "onlinechanger()")
```

А в функции уже расчет и вывод результата, как обычно.

Answer (score 2):

1. `document.getElementsByClassName('testt')[0].getAttribute('aria-valuetext')`
2. Работать будет, но зачем?

Comment: Да, вы правы, изменения "aria-valuetext" видны только при клике на ползунок. А когда его двигаешь - значение не меняется.

Answer (score -1):

```js
function renderPrice() {
    let price = document.querySelector('[aria-valuetext]').getAttribute('aria-valuetext');
    let priceField = document.querySelector('#resval');
    priceField.innerHTML = price;
}

document.addEventListener('click', renderPrice);
```

```html
<div class="testt" data-handle="0" tabindex="5" role="slider" aria-orientation="horizontal" aria-valuemin="0.0" aria-valuemax="100.0" aria-valuenow="25.0" aria-valuetext="4000" style="z-index: 4;"></div>
<button type="submit" id="super">Отправить</button>
<div id="resval"></div>
</div>
```

Событие onClick назначено на document.